# Regex in java compile

Tags: java, html, regex, swing, label

First of all, I know that parsing HTML with regex is bad.
But, luckily, the website I'm extracting code is simple, so I will always get good results using this method.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=<span class=\\\"itemName\\\">).*(?=</span>)"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(code);
```

That's supposed to return what is between the "itemname" tag and "span tag".
Something like that:

```
PESCA INSOLITA
```

But, instead of that, it returns:

```
PESCA INSOLITA</span></a><li><a href="/uy/synop...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* - You already answered that - *"I know that parsing HTML with regex is bad"* ... :-)

Answer (score 3):

You're using a greedy matcher with your `.*`. This is causing the matcher to match all the way to the last `span` tag in the HTML document. Instead, use `.*?`--or, better yet, use the parser...

Comment: The numbers of characters I want to get are irregular.

Comment: @SebaPaz I don't see why that would be relevant.